# PyParsing: What does Combine() do?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, pyparsing

What is the difference between:

```
foo = TOKEN1 + TOKEN2
```

and

```
foo = Combine(TOKEN1 + TOKEN2)
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Based on my experimentation, it seems like `Combine()` is for terminals, where you're trying to build an expression to match on, whereas plain `+` is for non-terminals. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Combine has 2 effects:

- it concatenates all the tokens into a single string
- it requires the matching tokens to all be adjacent with no intervening whitespace

If you create an expression like

```
realnum = Word(nums) + "." + Word(nums)
```

Then `realnum.parseString("3.14")` will return a list of 3 tokens: the leading '3', the '.', and the trailing '14'.  But if you wrap this in Combine, as in:

```
realnum = Combine(Word(nums) + "." + Word(nums))
```

then `realnum.parseString("3.14")` will return '3.14' (which you could then convert to a float using a parse action).  And since Combine suppresses pyparsing's default whitespace skipping between tokens, you won't accidentally find "3.14" in "The answer is 3. 14 is the next answer."

Comment: +1, a pretty authoritative answer (not all may realize Paul is the author of `pyparsing`, so I'm mostly pointing that out!-).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. And @Rosarch, welcome to pyparsing! These questions you are posting are very common for first-time pyparsing users, so keep plugging away.  I've tried to cover some of these points in the online wiki and docs, but I can see there is still a ways to go!

Comment: Yeah, I am fully aware that Paul is the author of pyparsing. It's great that you're on SO to provide noobs like me with guidance.