# pyparsing how to SkipTo end of indented block?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a structure like this with `pyparsing`:

```
identifier: some description text here which will wrap
    on to the next line. the follow-on text should be
    indented. it may contain identifier: and any text
    at all is allowed
next_identifier: more description, short this time
last_identifier: blah blah
```

I need something like:

```python
import pyparsing as pp

colon = pp.Suppress(':')
term = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_")
description = pp.SkipTo(next_identifier)
definition = term + colon + description
grammar = pp.OneOrMore(definition)
```

But I am struggling to define the `next_identifier` of the `SkipTo` clause since the identifiers may appear freely in the description text.

It seems that I need to include the indentation in the grammar, so that I can SkipTo the next non-indented line.

I tried:

```python
description = pp.Combine(
    pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd()) +
    pp.indentedBlock(
        pp.ZeroOrMore(
            pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd())
        ),
        indent_stack
    )
)
```

But I get the error:

```
ParseException: not a subentry (at char 55), (line:2, col:1)
```

Char 55 is at the very beginning of the run-on line:

```
...will wrap\n    on to the next line...
              ^
```

Which seems a bit odd, because that char position is clearly followed by the whitespace which makes it an indented subentry.

My traceback in ipdb looks like:

```
   5311     def checkSubIndent(s,l,t):
   5312         curCol = col(l,s)
   5313         if curCol > indentStack[-1]:
   5314             indentStack.append( curCol )
   5315         else:
-> 5316             raise ParseException(s,l,"not a subentry")
   5317

ipdb> indentStack
[1]
ipdb> curCol
1
```

I should add that the whole structure above that I'm matching *may also be indented* (by an unknown amount), so a solution like:

```python
description = pp.Combine(
    pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd()) + pp.LineEnd() +
    pp.ZeroOrMore(
        pp.White(' ') + pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd()) + pp.LineEnd()
    )
)
```

...which works for the example as presented will not work in my case as it will consume the subsequent definitions.

Comment: Are the lines indented with tabs or with a fixed number of blanks?

Comment: Do you have to handle multiple levels of indentation, or just one?

Comment: I'm parsing docstrings basically, so the depth of indent is unknown and there will be more than one level. I made a test suite here with some examples I need to handle https://gist.github.com/anentropic/e9b99faf0d9bd9e951cef6d8b4355e57

Comment: I realised part of my problem above is I need to consume the whitespace after the `LineEnd()` before entering the `indentedBlock` but I've been hitting my head on a wall all day trying satisfy all the cases. seems like it ought to be simple!

Comment: I really like this question, by the way, since it deals with a very flexible format for indentation, similar to how it is used in many markdown formats. I think it also highlights a minor bug/feature shortcoming in indentedBlock, in that it does not handle StringEnd or empty blocks very well.

Comment: @PaulMcG thanks again for your help. I have got this far with it https://gist.github.com/anentropic/674825da1377567a34ef4f0f6fe46fb7 and am a bit conceptually stuck. Needless to say I've never coded anything like this before. I think the scope of my problem is probably too big for this SO question

Comment: Make sure all your test strings fully unindented.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `indentedBlock`, the argument you pass in is the expression for each line in the block, so it shouldn't be a `indentedBlock(ZeroOrMore(line_expression), stack)`, just `indentedBlock(line_expression, stack)`. Pyparsing includes a builtin expression for "everything from here to the end of the line", titled `restOfLine`, so we will just use that for the expression for each line in the indented block:

```
import pyparsing as pp

NL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()

label = pp.ungroup(pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums+'_') + pp.Suppress(":"))

indent_stack = [1]
# see corrected version below
#description = pp.Group((pp.Empty() 
#                    + pp.restOfLine + NL
#                    + pp.ungroup(pp.indentedBlock(pp.restOfLine, indent_stack))))

description = pp.Group(pp.restOfLine + NL
                       + pp.Optional(pp.ungroup(~pp.StringEnd() 
                                                + pp.indentedBlock(pp.restOfLine, 
                                                                   indent_stack))))

labeled_text = pp.Group(label("label") + pp.Empty() + description("description"))
```

We use ungroup to remove the extra level of nesting created by `indentedBlock` but we also need to remove the per-line nesting that is created internally in `indentedBlock`. We do this with a parse action:

```
def combine_parts(tokens):
    # recombine description parts into a single list
    tt = tokens[0]
    new_desc = [tt.description[0]]
    new_desc.extend(t[0] for t in tt.description[1:])

    # reassign rebuild description into the parsed token structure 
    tt['description'] = new_desc
    tt[1][:] = new_desc

labeled_text.addParseAction(combine_parts)
```

At this point, we are pretty much done. Here is your sample text parsed and dumped:

```
parsed_data = (pp.OneOrMore(labeled_text)).parseString(sample)    
print(parsed_data[0].dump())

['identifier', ['some description text here which will wrap', 'on to the next line. the follow-on text should be', 'indented. it may contain identifier: and any text', 'at all is allowed']]
- description: ['some description text here which will wrap', 'on to the next line. the follow-on text should be', 'indented. it may contain identifier: and any text', 'at all is allowed']
- label: 'identifier'
```

Or this code to pull out the label and description fields:

```
for item in parsed_data:
    print(item.label)
    print('..' + '\n..'.join(item.description))
    print()

identifier
..some description text here which will wrap
..on to the next line. the follow-on text should be
..indented. it may contain identifier: and any text
..at all is allowed

next_identifier
..more description, short this time

last_identifier
..blah blah
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! This seems to only extract the first identifier though - I will try making the indented group `Optional`. Also I was puzzled why you define `definition` as a `Group` and then have a parse action to flatten the parts, so I tried changing the `Group` to `Combine` and that results in `ParseException: not a subentry (at char 55), (line:2, col:1)` and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are correct, the indented block needs to be made Optional. When I just made this optional, though, it got stuck in an infinite loop at the end of the string, so I also had to add the `~StringEnd()` negative lookahead. To see why I am flattening the data inside the parse action, comment out the addParseAction line and rerun (only the dump() code will work, the '..'.join code will raise exceptions) - you should see that there a couple of extra levels of nesting of the lines in the indented block. Lastly - Group and Combine are not interchangeable, see docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I realise that all my own attempts had got stuck because I was trying to wrap everything for the `description` in an outer `Combine` layer (to naively achieve what you did with a parse action)... if I understand right this didn't work because Combine was silently ignoring the sub-groups? Something like that? I could get the first line of multi-line description and could not understand why my `Optional(indentedBlock)` was not matching.

Comment: This question+answer might help clear things up for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940489/pyparsing-what-does-combine-do